# Should I expose async methods?

Tags: vb.net, async-await

I'm developing a class library (for use by other developers) which wraps a RESTful web service. I'm using the `HttpClient` type from the `System.Net.Http` namespace to do all of my API calls, asynchronously.

In addition to simply sending/receiving content, I want to do additional processing on the returned XML data. No matter how you put it, this involves using the Async/Await keywords somewhere in the class library.

My question is whether it's a good or bad idea to expose methods which use the Async keyword, and why. I've read somewhere that you should make the Async method private, then create an additional method with just a return statement. That's what I've been doing, but it doesn't feel right.

```
Public Function InvokeAsync(command As HttpRequestMessage) As Task(Of CommandResult)
    Return InvokeAsyncInternal(command)
End Function

Private Async Function InvokeAsyncInternal(command As HttpRequestMessage) As Task(Of CommandResult)
    Dim rawCommandResult As HttpResponseMessage = Await myHttpClient.SendAsync(command)
    Dim finalResult As CommandResult = AdditionalProcessing(rawCommandResult)
    Return finalResult
End Function
```

Keeping in mind that this is an oversimplified code sample: are there any good arguments not to expose the Async method directly?

Comment: “I've read somewhere …” Where did you read that? Do you have a link? In general, I think you shouldn't do something just because someone says so. You should do it because their argument makes sense and you agree with it.

Comment: It was one of the many "introduction to async/await" blog posts somewhere on the internet. It made sense at the time, but now I'm starting to reconsider because it doesn't seem to add any value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has to do with the compiler transformation; you can separate the "real" `Async` method from its `Public` counterpart, and you get the same benefits as when you do the same kind of separation for iterator (`Yield`) methods.

In particular, exceptions are handled differently when thrown from the wrapper than when thrown from the `Async` method. When an `Async` method that returns `Task` throws an `Exception`, it's placed on the returned `Task` rather than thrown directly to the caller. When the `Public` wrapper method (which is not `Async`) throws an `Exception`, it's thrown directly to the caller.

So, precondition-style checks can be put in the `Public` method. Callers can ignore exceptions placed on `Task`s, but they can't ignore exceptions thrown directly. Placing precondition exceptions in a `Public` wrapper forces the caller to realize they are misusing the API, and also permits a separation of usage exceptions (which are thrown directly) from runtime exceptions (which are placed on the `Task`).

If your method has no preconditions, then your `Public` wrapper is just returning the inner `Task`. In this case, the `Public` wrapper is unnecessary.

Comment: So wrapping my methods only to avoid exposing methods with the `Async` or `Iterator` keyword is completely pointless? Bad input is properly handled by the web service so I don't have to worry about validation.

Comment: It isn't pointless, sometimes it is necessary. For example, when you throw exception in the first part of the application, you will not get that exception naturally unless you await the function.

Comment: @ToniPetrina But wrapping the method doesn't do anything. It won't affect how the exception is represented.

Comment: Of course it affects! Two people are arguing against you (Stephen and me), don't you think that signifies something?

Comment: @StevenDotNet: I would consider *input validation* an example of a runtime error, which should not go into the `Public` wrapper anyway. I would only put [boneheaded exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) in a wrapper method. That said, I never actually follow this pattern (I do expose my `async` methods directly). If you write mostly-`async` code, the "natural" way to expect exceptions *is* on the `Task` type, not raised directly at the point of the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following scenario:

```
void Caller()
{
    var t = AsyncThatThrows(null);
    // ...
    Task.WaitAny(t, t2); // <-- exception thrown here
}

Task AsyncThatThrows(Object o)
{
    if (o == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("o");

    // ...
    await // ...
    // ...
}
```

Note that the exception is thrown *before* the first await, but the exception is rethrown only on inspecting the Task. Whether by awaiting it or by getting its Result. If you choose to implement it in the following way:

```
void Caller()
{
    var t = AsyncThatThrows(null);// <-- exception thrown here
    // ...
    Task.WaitAny(t, t2);
}

Task AsyncThatThrows(Object o)
{
    if (o == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("o");

    return AsyncThatThrows_Impl(o);
}

Task AsyncThatThrows_Impl(Object o)
{
    // ...
    await // ...
    // ...
}
```

Now the exception can be caught *at its invocation*, you don't have to inspect the Task. In the former case, even though we still haven't started asynchronous part yet, the exception will be stored in the resulting Task nonetheless.

Comment: This stuff is seriously difficult to grasp for someone who has no idea what the compiler does